# Android: Modifying top right clock in notification bar

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, clock

I am using Eclipse with ADT to develop apps for Android (ICS) and have got an HTC Sensation phone. Is there any possibility to modify the digital clock which is shown on the right hand side in the status bar that way to make it show the seconds in addition to hours and minutes?

If possible, could someone post some code which accesses the HTC status bar and/or the clock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, as you do not have access to the notification bar's clock, or battery indicator etc.